# Python Apache beam SDK: ReadFromKafka can't consume the data (error)?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam

Running env:

- OS: ubuntu 20.04
- kafka version: 2.12-2.0.1
- apach-beam library version: `apache-beam==2.32.0`

Procedure:

**shell 1**: Run below code

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.external.kafka import ReadFromKafka

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(["--runner=DirectRunner"])


def run():
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        _ = (
            p
            | 'ReadData' >> ReadFromKafka(
                consumer_config={"bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"},
                topics=["my-first-topic"],
            )
            | 'PrintData' >> beam.Map(print)
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

**output of shell1**:

```
WARNING:apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_environment:You have limited Interactive Beam features since your ipython kernel is not connected to any notebook frontend.
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.8 interpreter.
2.32.0: Pulling from apache/beam_java11_sdk
Digest: sha256:a45f89584071950d371966abf910869c456179ab54c7b5213e3f4e2a54bd2753
Status: Image is up to date for apache/beam_java11_sdk:2.32.0
docker.io/apache/beam_java11_sdk:2.32.0
```

**shell 2**:

```
$ cd kafka_2.12-2.0.1/bin && ./kafka-console-producer.sh --topic "my-first-topic" --broker-list localhost:9092

>2
>3
>4
```

**output of shell 1**:

```
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.8 interpreter.
2.32.0: Pulling from apache/beam_java11_sdk
Digest: sha256:a45f89584071950d371966abf910869c456179ab54c7b5213e3f4e2a54bd2753
Status: Image is up to date for apache/beam_java11_sdk:2.32.0
docker.io/apache/beam_java11_sdk:2.32.0
ERROR:root:severity: ERROR
timestamp {
  seconds: 1630485467
  nanos: 764000000
}
message: "Client failed to deque and process the value"
trace: "org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element \'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord@4c9edf30\' with coder \'KafkaRecordCoder(ByteArrayCoder,ByteArrayCoder)\'.\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1683)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2205)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$ProcessBundleContextBase.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2374)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:142)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:750)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:266)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1680)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$WindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2092)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.outputWithTimestamp(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn.processElement(ReadFromKafkaDoFn.java:378)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForWindowObservingSizedElementAndRestriction(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1048)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$1000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:637)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:632)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:266)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:221)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.DecodingFnDataReceiver.accept(DecodingFnDataReceiver.java:43)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.DecodingFnDataReceiver.accept(DecodingFnDataReceiver.java:25)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.QueueingBeamFnDataClient$ConsumerAndData.accept(QueueingBeamFnDataClient.java:316)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.QueueingBeamFnDataClient.drainAndBlock(QueueingBeamFnDataClient.java:219)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:329)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:140)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:110)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element \'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord@4c9edf30\' with coder \'KafkaRecordCoder(ByteArrayCoder,ByteArrayCoder)\'.\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.getEncodedElementByteSize(Coder.java:300)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.registerByteSizeObserver(Coder.java:291)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$SampleByteSizeDistribution.tryUpdate(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:385)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:259)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)\nCaused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null byte[]\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:56)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:41)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.encode(KvCoder.java:72)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.encode(KvCoder.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecordCoder.encode(KafkaRecordCoder.java:70)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecordCoder.encode(KafkaRecordCoder.java:40)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.getEncodedElementByteSize(Coder.java:297)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.registerByteSizeObserver(Coder.java:291)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$SampleByteSizeDistribution.tryUpdate(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:385)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:259)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1680)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2205)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$ProcessBundleContextBase.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2374)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:142)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:750)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:266)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1680)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$WindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2092)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.outputWithTimestamp(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn.processElement(ReadFromKafkaDoFn.java:378)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForWindowObservingSizedElementAndRestriction(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1048)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$1000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:637)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:632)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:266)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:221)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.DecodingFnDataReceiver.accept(DecodingFnDataReceiver.java:43)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.DecodingFnDataReceiver.accept(DecodingFnDataReceiver.java:25)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.QueueingBeamFnDataClient$ConsumerAndData.accept(QueueingBeamFnDataClient.java:316)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.QueueingBeamFnDataClient.drainAndBlock(QueueingBeamFnDataClient.java:219)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:329)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:140)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:110)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n"
instruction_id: "bundle_116"
log_location: "org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.QueueingBeamFnDataClient"
thread: "31"

ERROR:root:severity: ERROR
timestamp {
  seconds: 1630485467
  nanos: 770000000
}
message: "Exception while trying to handle InstructionRequest bundle_116"
trace: "org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element \'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord@4c9edf30\' with coder \'KafkaRecordCoder(ByteArrayCoder,ByteArrayCoder)\'.

...
 

/home/newdisk/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py in _run_bundle(self, runner_execution_context, bundle_context_manager, data_input, data_output, input_timers, expected_timer_output, bundle_manager)
    767         expected_timer_output)
    768
--> 769     result, splits = bundle_manager.process_bundle(
    770         data_input, data_output, input_timers, expected_timer_output)
    771     # Now we collect all the deferred inputs remaining from bundle execution.

/home/newdisk/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py in process_bundle(self, inputs, expected_outputs, fired_timers, expected_output_timers, dry_run)
   1118
   1119     if result.error:
-> 1120       raise RuntimeError(result.error)
   1121
   1122     if result.process_bundle.requires_finalization:

RuntimeError: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord@4c9edf30' with coder 'KafkaRecordCoder(ByteArrayCoder,ByteArrayCoder)'.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1683)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2205)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$ProcessBundleContextBase.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2374)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:142)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:750)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:266)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1680)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$WindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2092)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.outputWithTimestamp(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:87)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn.processElement(ReadFromKafkaDoFn.java:378)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForWindowObservingSizedElementAndRestriction(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1048)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$1000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:637)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:632)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:266)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:221)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.DecodingFnDataReceiver.accept(DecodingFnDataReceiver.java:43)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.DecodingFnDataReceiver.accept(DecodingFnDataReceiver.java:25)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.QueueingBeamFnDataClient$ConsumerAndData.accept(QueueingBeamFnDataClient.java:316)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.QueueingBeamFnDataClient.drainAndBlock(QueueingBeamFnDataClient.java:219)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:329)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:140)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:110)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord@4c9edf30' with coder 'KafkaRecordCoder(ByteArrayCoder,ByteArrayCoder)'.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.getEncodedElementByteSize(Coder.java:300)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.registerByteSizeObserver(Coder.java:291)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$SampleByteSizeDistribution.tryUpdate(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:385)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:259)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null byte[]
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:63)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:56)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:41)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.encode(KvCoder.java:72)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.encode(KvCoder.java:63)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecordCoder.encode(KafkaRecordCoder.java:70)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecordCoder.encode(KafkaRecordCoder.java:40)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.getEncodedElementByteSize(Coder.java:297)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.registerByteSizeObserver(Coder.java:291)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$SampleByteSizeDistribution.tryUpdate(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:385)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:259)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1680)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2205)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$ProcessBundleContextBase.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2374)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:142)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:750)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:266)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1680)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$WindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2092)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.outputWithTimestamp(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:87)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn.processElement(ReadFromKafkaDoFn.java:378)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForWindowObservingSizedElementAndRestriction(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1048)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$1000(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:139)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:637)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:632)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:266)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:221)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.DecodingFnDataReceiver.accept(DecodingFnDataReceiver.java:43)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.DecodingFnDataReceiver.accept(DecodingFnDataReceiver.java:25)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.QueueingBeamFnDataClient$ConsumerAndData.accept(QueueingBeamFnDataClient.java:316)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.QueueingBeamFnDataClient.drainAndBlock(QueueingBeamFnDataClient.java:219)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:329)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:140)
    at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:110)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Looks like it is related with `key_deserializer` and `value_deserializer` args of `ReadFromKafka`, So I tried to change them:

```
# key_deserializer="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
# value_deserializer="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
```

But it raised an another error:

```
RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to build transform beam:external:java:kafkaio:typedwithoutmetadata:v1 from spec urn: "beam:external:java:kafkaio:typedwithoutmetadata:v1"
payload: "\n\213\002\n\035\n\017consumer_config\032\n*\b\n\002\020\a\022\002\020\a\n\020\n\006topics\032\006\032\004\n\002\020\a\n\026\n\020key_deserializer\032\002\020\a\n\030\n\022value_deserializer\032\002\020\a\n\027\n\017start_read_time\032\004\b\001\020\004\n\027\n\017max_num_records\032\004\b\001\020\004\n\025\n\rmax_read_time\032\004\b\001\020\004\n\037\n\031commit_offset_in_finalize\032\002\020\b\n\026\n\020timestamp_policy\032\002\020\a\022$6a700b0b-2839-492d-8629-9b3268d90919\022\272\001\t\002p\000\000\000\000\001\021bootstrap.servers\016localhost:9092\000\000\000\001\016my-first-topic6org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer6org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer\000\016ProcessingTime"
```

What's wrong with them? Anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. It turned out the smoking gun was this line in the traceback:

```
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null byte[]
```

What it's saying is that there's a `null` value value somewhere and it can't encode it. For me, it turned out I was sending `key=None` in my kafka-python `producer.send` function and changing the `key` value to a string fixed the issue. For example:

```py
with open("../data/sample_data.json") as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        producer.send(KAFKA_TOPIC, key=str.encode("foo"), value=str.encode(line))
```

You can also set the `key_serializer` and `value_serializer` in the `KafkaProducer` object.

A heads up: even after fixing the null read there are still problems with reading from Kafka in Python outside of the Dataflow Runner. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-11998

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As i figured out, ReadFromKafka wants to read the Data in a **key:value** format. My solution was to start the kafka-console-producer.sh with the option:

```
--property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:"
```

and add data in the format key:value (f.e. name:peter instead of peter)